# AutoMapper: Mapping between DTO and Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, automapper

I am working with a ASP.NET Core WebAPI and I want to do CRUD for my objects called "Item".
I am using EF Core to work with a SQL Database and I have two models that represents my objects.

1. **ItemDto** - Data Transfer Object for an Item
2. **ItemEntity** - Database Object (represents a row in a table 1:1)

My HTTP GET one and HTTP GET many methods works in such way that it

1. Get ItemRepository instance
2. Fetch one or more **ItemEntity**
3. Map it to **ItemDto** by using AutoMapper
   This is initalized in my constructor such as

   ```
   m_itemDtoMapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ItemEntity, ItemDto>()));
   ```

And in my WebAPI method I map it to a ItemDto with the following line (for the GET many case):

```
var itemDtos = m_itemDtoMapper.Map<IEnumerable<ItemEntity>, ICollection<ItemDto>>(items);
```

This works well and the AutoMapper is very powerful. The questions I have now is:

1. Is this the standard way of managing the relationship between database entities and data transfer objects?
2. In the CreateItem method, I need to do reverse mapping. Instead of mapping ItemEntity to ItemDto, I need to map a ItemDto to an ItemEntity. How shall I do this? Creating a copy of my mapper just with switched entities works but is that how its supposed to be done? i.e two mappers.

Comment: Do not use m_ as prefix, underscore is enough for C# :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, it seems that you initialize each time a new mapper instance. I would suggest you go along with dependency injection and make use of AutoMapper Mapping Profiles.

You can do it in three simple steps and I think it answers both of your questions:

**Step 1:**
Simply create a new class called MappingProfile or something similar:

```cs
   public class MappingProfile: Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<User, AuthenticateDto>(); // One Way
            CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap(); // Reverse
        }
    }
```

**Step 2:** Register Automapper in Startup.cs

```cs
   // Register AutoMapper
   services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

**Step 3:** Consume your mapper over DI

```cs
  public UserService(IMapper mapper) {
   _mapper = mapper;
  }
// call it as you already did
_mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(user);
```

Hopefully it helps you :)